# How to reduce the size of electron app with some packager?

Tags: node.js, electron

Now I make an electron app with python server init. But after packaging, the size of app is 312M. So I want to reduce size to at least 100M.

Comment: Try a module cleanup. Optimize assets. Try using a runtime such as electrino if feasible. Use a runtime exe compressor/decompressor. Pack the app into installers with compression.

Comment: @NickM  , I don't know why electrino has been recommended , while it is just a basic idea.